# Spring WebClient endpoints defined in interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I've asked a question how to replace JAXrs client with Spring alternative, which was not answered, but I think I know the answer now with WHAT to replace the jax but not how.

I decided I'm going to use Spring's WebClient since RestTemplate is in maintenance mode and will be deprecated in future.

Now with knowing I should use WebClient - I've another question.

If I have an interface with annotated Rest Endpoints , how do I put this interface in use with WebClient? Or should I just simply create request with url's and http methods separately in each method?

I've this interface

```
@RequestMapping("/theResource")
public interface TheResource {

    @GetMapping( value = "/test")
    ResponseEntity<String> test();
```

and I am wondering if there is a way to use this information in WebClient?

I know I could do

```
WebClient.RequestBodySpec uri = client
  .method(HttpMethod.GET)
  .uri("/theResource/test");
```

But is there any way to just create WebClient with interface mentioned above?

I've asked the original question here
[Spring alternative to JAXRSClientFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522087/spring-alternative-to-jaxrsclientfactory)

Comment: Sure, you could use reflection to access the annotations of TheResource, but do you have access to it in the first place? Usually the REST controllers are not exported to clients (unlike SOAP where you usually had access to the WSDL).

Comment: That's an idea but I was hoping for something more "in-the-box", like method that just takes the class of TheResource interface and then you just call

  ResponseEntity<String> response = theResource.test();

whilst theResource would be created such as

T resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create(TheResource.class...)

note that I do not want JAXRSClientFactory I am trying to migrate to spring solution but can't find something similar to it

Comment: That's exactly what SOAP was about - generating clients from definitions. There are a few mechanisms for REST out there but you would need a language like RAML to describe your REST API and generate clients from it.

Comment: hmm at least now I know what I should look into, the RAML thing sounds good.